# Use users / logins from another database

Tags: sql-server, security

Is it possible to use logins/users from one database(F) in another(S) one? I know I can copy it but, when I add user to (F) database I have to copy again them all (or add the same user to (S) database) - I want to avoid that...

All I want is to know if is it possible to set Security/Users to Users from another database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means that database users have no matching server logins.

That is, each database [sys.database_principals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187328%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) has no match in [sys.server_principals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188786.aspx)

For Windows logins this is easy. This generates your missing CREATE LOGINS

```
USE MyDB
SELECT
    'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(SUSER_SNAME(sid)) + ' FROM WINDOWS'
FROM
    sys.database_principals DP
WHERE
    DP.type IN ('G', 'U')
    AND 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals SP WHERE SP.sid = DP.sid);
```

For SQL Logins, you need to recreate it with the correct SID.

```
SELECT 
    'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(DP.name) + 
                ' WITH PASSWORD = ''ChangeMe'', SID = ' + 
                CONVERT(varchar(128), sid, 1)
FROM
    sys.database_principals DP
WHERE
    DP.type = 'S' AND DP.principal_id > 4 
    AND 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals SP WHERE SP.sid = DP.sid);
```

Note that [sp_change_users_login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174378%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) is deprecated.

Now, if your SQL Logins already exist, then the names match but the sid values are different. For this you use [ALTER USER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060.aspx) use the LOGIN option.

Finally, the SQL Login passwords can be recreated if you have a backup of the "old" master database. If you restore this as, say, FixLogins then you can use this

```
SELECT 
    'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(DP.name) + 
                ' WITH PASSWORD = ' + CONVERT(varchar(256), SL.password_hash, 1) + ' HASHED, SID = ' + 
                CONVERT(varchar(128), DP.sid, 1)

FROM
    sys.database_principals DP
    JOIN
    FixLogins.sys.sql_logins SL ON DP.sid = SL.sid  
WHERE
    DP.type = 'S' AND DP.principal_id > 4 
    AND 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals SP WHERE SP.sid = DP.sid);
```